# xetex not working

Tags: xetex

I have installed Emacs and AUCTeX on Ubuntu 16.04 a week ago. LaTeX works fine, but when I try to compile with XeTeX, it shows "LaTeX: Problems after [0] pages." Can someone help?

Earlier I was using fedora 20 and was using XeTex for compiling my latex files. Now those files could not be compiled. What is the problem? Though I use LaTeX extensively to prepare notes and write books, I don't have much knowledge of Linux.

Comment: Can you prepare some code and test ist on the command line? Can you find any more information (for example in the log-file) than `LaTeX: Problems after [0] pages.`? In order to help you, we need to know a little bit more...

Comment: Thanks DG'. This solved my problem. When I run xelatex in command mode, it said xelatex not installed. So I installed it and now it is WORIKING.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments